# java use methods automatically?

Tags: java, awt

In the oracle site I found a class to load an image. I tried to run it but the things that I don't understand is how the methods Paint and GetPreferredSize are launched without been call.

This is the class: [LoadImageApp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java)

Can you kindly explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those methods **override** methods in the base class.

The AWT base classes call those methods to arrange and render the UI

Comment: only the basics classes of java have this behave when I override a methods?

Comment: @MassimoZampieri: That statement is meaningless.  Any class can call any method, and any non-`final` method can be overridden.